# Turn off alerts on a SharePoint List

Tags: sharepoint-2010, alerts

We have a SharePoint solution that uses a standard task list.

We would like to turn off alerts for when items change in / are added to the task list.

Is there a way to do this in code, either when we create the site, or when we add items to the task list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SPList.EnableAssignedToEmail](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splist.enableassigntoemail.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, in our case it was a little more complicated, there was a workflow, that for some reason was turning it back on again.